# Get collision details from Rectangle.Intersects()

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, physics

I have a Breakout game in which, at some point, I detect the collision between the ball and the paddle with something like this:

```
// Ball class
rectangle.Intersects(paddle.Rectangle);
```

Is there any way I can get the exact coordinates of the collision, or any details about it, with the current `XNA API`?

I thought of doing some basic calculations, such as comparing the exact coordinates of each object on the moment of the collision. It would look something like this:

```
// Ball class
if((rectangle.X - paddle.Rectangle.X) < (paddle.Rectangle.Width / 2))
    // Collision happened on the left side
else
    // Collision happened on the right side
```

But I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it.

Do you guys have any tips on maybe an engine I might have to use to achieve that? Or even good coding practices using this method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XNA's rectangles are pretty limited. The `Rectangle.Intersects()` method only returns a boolean result, so you'll need to do more tests yourself if you want details. You can, however, use the `Rectangle.Intersect(Rectangle, Rectangle)` method to get the rectangle where the two overlap. That will give you some information on depth and location, at least.

Comment: Is this `get the rectangle where the two overlap` functionallity available on the `XNA API` or I have to download some extra stuff, like the `Platformer Starter Kit`?

Comment: Which method is this? I don't recall that XNA 4.0 supports `Rectangle Rectangle.Intersects(...)`.

Comment: Someone gave me the right at stackoverflow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersect.aspx

Comment: Ok, with the returned Rectangle, how can I check the position of the paddle that got collided by the ball?

Comment: If you know that the paddle and ball are intersecting then you use the location information of the paddle rectangle that you checked in the first place, i.e. `rectangle.X` or `rectangle.Y` or whatever you want to access.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** If you're using MonoGame, then as of 3.0 beta, `Rectangle Rectangle.Intersect(rectangle, rectangle)` doesn't exist. You can use the below code from the XNA Platformer kit instead.

---

You can download the XNA Platformer Starter Kit ([ported to Windows 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davrous/windows-phone-7-platformer-starter-kit-for-xna-studio-4-0)). It ships with a helper extension method that returns a rectangle describing the intersection of two rectangles:

```
static class RectangleExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the signed depth of intersection between two rectangles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The amount of overlap between two intersecting rectangles. These
        /// depth values can be negative depending on which wides the rectangles
        /// intersect. This allows callers to determine the correct direction
        /// to push objects in order to resolve collisions.
        /// If the rectangles are not intersecting, Vector2.Zero is returned.
        /// </returns>
        public static Vector2 GetIntersectionDepth(this Rectangle rectA, Rectangle rectB)
        {
            // Calculate half sizes.
            float halfWidthA = rectA.Width / 2.0f;
            float halfHeightA = rectA.Height / 2.0f;
            float halfWidthB = rectB.Width / 2.0f;
            float halfHeightB = rectB.Height / 2.0f;

            // Calculate centers.
            Vector2 centerA = new Vector2(rectA.Left + halfWidthA, rectA.Top + halfHeightA);
            Vector2 centerB = new Vector2(rectB.Left + halfWidthB, rectB.Top + halfHeightB);

            // Calculate current and minimum-non-intersecting distances between centers.
            float distanceX = centerA.X - centerB.X;
            float distanceY = centerA.Y - centerB.Y;
            float minDistanceX = halfWidthA + halfWidthB;
            float minDistanceY = halfHeightA + halfHeightB;

            // If we are not intersecting at all, return (0, 0).
            if (Math.Abs(distanceX) >= minDistanceX || Math.Abs(distanceY) >= minDistanceY)
                return Vector2.Zero;

            // Calculate and return intersection depths.
            float depthX = distanceX > 0 ? minDistanceX - distanceX : -minDistanceX - distanceX;
            float depthY = distanceY > 0 ? minDistanceY - distanceY : -minDistanceY - distanceY;
            return new Vector2(depthX, depthY);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the position of the center of the bottom edge of the rectangle.
        /// </summary>
        public static Vector2 GetBottomCenter(this Rectangle rect)
        {
            return new Vector2(rect.X + rect.Width / 2.0f, rect.Bottom);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this link. May I ask you why did you need to use a modified version? Is that port official?

Comment: @DanielRibeiro I checked my history and apparently I didn't modify it after all. The port is unofficial; I simply couldn't find the original. It works with MonoGame/C#, which was good enough for me.

Comment: But there is an original port, right? Isn't this supposed to be such a simple feature? Anyways, I'm not using MonoGame, just XNA. Would you still recommend me to use this port?

Comment: I had to set the correct answer to `ssb`, but thank you very much for this. I'll for sure get into this port! Many thanks!

Comment: @DanielRibeiro ah, I see. I think that method doesn't exist in MonoGame, which is why I ended up using this approach. Cheers though.

Comment: The method is `Rectangle.Intersect`, singular. Just to clarify.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro the signature is `Rectangle Rectangle.Intersects(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)`. This method is officially in XNA 4.0, but not MonoGame.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6794/discussion-between-daniel-ribeiro-and-ashes999)

Comment: No need to. As you can see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersect.aspx, the correct signature is on singular `Rectangle.Intersect(Rectangle, Rectangle)`, as I said before. It's important to notify this difference, so people won't confuse them later on.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro I don't understand. But please edit my answer as you see fit.